# Why file.write returns an int?

Tags: python

Why is `MT2` here an int? When I run the code Python gives an error because of it. Shouldn't it only be an int if it's all numbers?

```
MT1=open('mean_temp.txt', 'a+')
#Write a new line for Rio de Janeiro "Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n"
MT1.seek(0,2)
MT2=MT1.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
MT2.seek(0)
headings=MT2.readline()
headings.split(',')
city_temp=MT2.readline()
city_temp.split(',')
print('a:\n', city_temp)
MT1.close()
```

Comment: On the side note, you should take a look at naming convention https://www.pythonsheets.com/notes/python-basic.html#python-naming-rule

Answer (score 6):

This is because of the line

```
MT2=MT1.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
```

The `write` method returns *the number of bytes written*. So, after that, `MT2` is an integer equal to the length of the string you wrote.

Comment: +1, although "an integer equal to the length of the string you wrote" is a bit optimistic: how about `"あ"`?

Comment: @DavinTryon https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html, but you have to ctrl-f it.

Comment: @DavinTryon https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects "f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written."

Comment: @Rightleg: i talked about *his case*. It's very unlikely that he gets anything else.